# F# error 'error FS0039: The namespace or module 'MySql' is not defined'?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

Hello
 I try to connect F# and MySQL database, but i got fallowing error :error FS0039: The namespace or module 'MySql' is not defined.
 So far,i tried to reference the folder which contains MySQL.Data.dll:project -> add reference->browse -> C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.6\Assemblies\v2.0
 Also i tired to reference MySQL.Data,too.
But each time,i get this error.
Thanks for your help.
Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F# interactive window is unaware of your project references, so you need to explicitly register them using the `#r` directive.  For example, try typing `#r "MySql.Data"` or `#r @"C:\...\MySql.Data.dll"` into F# interactive before attempting to use any of the types in the `MySql` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Or If you added the any framework / Extensions into your solution. You may right click the reference folder in the Solution Explorer then click "Send Reference to F# Interactive"

Comment: Should not it be in comment?