# Using and installing MathNet Package

Tags: f#, installation, f#-interactive, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I have installed the MathNet.Numerics package on Visual Studio 2017 using the Package Manager Console.

I have attempted to open a Source File on and execute an algorithm relating to the MersenneTwister type within the MathNet namespace.

However, when I try to generate numbers using this algorithm in F# Interactive, I am met with the error:

> File1.fs(3,6): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'MathNet' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
>
> Math

Code is as per below:

```
module File1

open MathNet.Numerics.Random

let mersenneTwister = new MersenneTwister(42)
let a = mersenneTwister.NextDouble()
```

Apologies if this is unclear, I am relatively new to F# :)

Comment: If you're executing this from an fsx script in F# Interactive you need to reference the library with the `#r` directive. If you have this compiled you need to add the reference to the project.

Comment: I was previously running from a fs script. I have now tried using an fsx script, and have now referenced the dll for MathNet.Numerics as located on my PC in my project file. 

I have also loaded the reference to this dll for the project file. However, this dll is sitting in the Browse dialog section of Reference Manager, and I am not sure if this is correct?

Comment: You can a) generate a compiled exe and execute that (you will need to reference the package in VS or b) execute it with FSI as a script, you will need to show the path to the exe with the `#r` directive. If you come by the FSSF Slack many will be able to help you. Or just ping me in the F# chat here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Are you per change using the interactive window or running an `fsx` script? Cause these [don't recognize your packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997209/2877982).

When reproducing your problem in a `F#` console app I got this output: `Hello 0.374540`.

I installed the `MathNet.Numerics.fsharp` nuget package (which also uses the package you mention) and used the following code in the `Program.fs`:

```
open MathNet.Numerics.Random

let hello () =
    let mersenneTwister = new MersenneTwister(42)
    let a = mersenneTwister.NextDouble()
    printfn "Hello %f" a

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    hello ()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

If you *do* want to use the `nuget package` from a script you can reference it in the top of your script like so (absolute or [relative](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work/#2-use-f-to-test-your-own-code-interactively))

`#r @"C:\Path\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll"`

Comment: Hi, I installed the MathNet package via Package Manager Console. I have been running a fs script.

I have been executing the code via F# Interactive, which may be causing the issue. However, I have tried following the steps you stated and am still having the same errors come up.

For learning purposes, is this code not executable using F# Interactive window? If so why? And is there a way to execute this code without using F# Interactive?

Thanks in advance :)